# TextView indentation on the right

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I need to indent the same size in the second text view on the right as in the first one on the left. I tried to do through

```
android: text alignment = "textend"
android: layout_margin End = "20dp",
```

now I have it done like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TestTest"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:text="TestTest"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

but I think it should be done differently
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTmq1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `layout_gravity` and set it to `end` to push the 2nd textView towards the end.

```
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TestTest1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="TestTest1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Also note I have set the width to `wrap_content` as opposed to `match_parent`.
Have also used a margin of 20 dp to offset the 2nd TextView from the edge of parent.

TextAlignment attribute specifies the position of text inside the TextView and won't work if the view is set to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

Using `android:weightSum` You Can Separate.

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Then For Second TextView Only Use `android:textAlignment="viewEnd"` Then Text Gravity Goes To Width End